# How to handle foreach / group by with 400K data the fastest way?

Tags: c#, sql

I have a log-table where every single user login is logged.
At the moment we are nearly to 500K rows here.

Now I want to make a statistic of this data, what we have saved is the browser string:
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0"

What I want to get are 2 informations:
1) Browser and Count of this Browser
2) OS and Count of this OS

As far as I see I have too options here:
1) making a SQL Statement to get this data with a group by like
Something like:

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN [F_BROWSER] like '%Linux%' then 'Linux'
       WHEN [F_BROWSER] like '%WINDOWS NT 4.0%' then 'WINDOWS NT 4.0'
       WHEN [F_BROWSER] like '%WINDOWS NT 5.0%' then 'WINDOWS NT 5.0'
       WHEN [F_BROWSER] like '%WINDOWS NT 5.1%' then 'WINDOWS NT 5.1'
       WHEN [F_BROWSER] like '%WINDOWS NT 6.0%' then 'WINDOWS NT 6.0'
       WHEN [F_BROWSER] like '%WINDOWS NT 6.1%' then 'WINDOWS NT 6.1'
      End as OS
  FROM [D_USER].[dbo].[T_LOGIN]
```

The problem: even with only this 6 test values the query is around 20 seconds. And I will end up having more data every day and a lot more then this 6 cases here...

2) Loading all Browser data and foreach them in C#.

I didn't tested this yet.

Any idea what is the fastest solution for this?
Maybe a better Idea then my two options here?

Comment: An `Index` on `F_BROWSER`?

Comment: Why not just keep a running total of the values rather than querying each time you want to see the data.

Comment: Is it possible to alter this table?

Comment: You have to show us the actual query in order for us to help you with it.  Your current snippet doesn't even have the group by clause.

Comment: i dont know if it would speed up anything but you could try grouping the data by `F_BROWSER` first, and then applying your case statement to the grouped data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you will keep using this statistical information in future. You cannot swallow a big piece in one shot. I would write a background job (console app, sql job what ever.) and will go through entire table and parse required information from your table and put it into well indexed columns.

1. Add 2 more extra columns into your table and index them: Browser, OS
2. Preferably your columns should have integer values and create separate tables for different browser types and OS. So different browsers will indicate different int values.
3. On first run of your scheduled task, go through items by batch (1K per loop) and parse values into newly added columns.
4. Next time your scheduled job runs, only parse rows which have null value in those two columns. So you will stay updated.
5. You can run your aggregation functions much faster because your columns are indexed and well separated.

Answer (score 1):

Let the RDBMS (SQL Server?) do the heavy lifting here.  One of the main benefits to this approach is that you don't unnecessarily have more data traveling *from* the RDBMS *to* the application.  Keep the data transfer narrow (i.e. aggregate the data on the database side).

Another issue is with your actual data.  `F_BROWSER` isn't a great candidate for aggregation on the OS, as the column has more data in it causing you to do string matches.  If you can, you should have individual fields for OS, browser, etc.  That way the aggregation will be easier on you (with the query) as well as the RDBMS.  Parse that browser/OS information on the way *in* to the database so that you don't need to massage it on the way out.